# How to upload images in s3 bucket using angular ng2-file-upload?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, amazon-s3, ng2-file-upload

Here which code should need to change for upload images on s3 bucket.

```
uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url: URL,
    disableMultipart: true,
    formatDataFunctionIsAsync: true,
    formatDataFunction: async (item) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({
          name: item._file.name,
          length: item._file.size,
          contentType: item._file.type,
          date: new Date()
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented in this method.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // upload image on aws 
   this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (item => {
        // Here S3 image upload code.  
    });
})
```